# Matching an optional substring in a regex

Tags: regex

I'm developing an algorithm to parse a number out of a series of short-ish strings. These strings are somewhat regular, but there's a few different general forms and several exceptions. I'm trying to build a set of regexes that will handle the various forms and exceptions; I'll apply them one after another to see if I get a match.

One of these forms goes something like this:

```
X (Y) Z
```

Where:

- `X` is a number I want to capture.
- `Z` is static, pre-defined text. it's basically how I determine whether this particular form is applicable or not.
- `Y` is a string of unknown length and content, surrounded by parenthesis.

Also: `Y` is optional; it doesn't always appear in a string with `Z` and `X`. So, I want to be able to extract the numbers from all of these strings:

- `10 Z`
- `20 (foo) Z`
- `30 (bar) Z`

Right now, I have a regex that will capture the first one:

```
([0-9]+) +Z
```

My problem is that I don't know how to construct a regex that will match a series of characters if and only if they're enclosed in parenthesis. Can this be done in a single regex?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
(\d+)\s+(\(.*?\))?\s?Z
```

Note the escaped parentheses, and the `?` (zero or once) quantifiers. Any of the groups you don't want to capture can be (`?:` non-capture groups).

I agree about the spaces. `\s` is a better option there. I also changed the quantifier to insure there are digits at the beginning. As far as newlines, that would depend on context: if the file is parsed line by line it won't be a problem. Another option is to anchor the start and end of the line (add a `^` at the front and a `$` at the end).

Comment: The spaces are static. Replace them with \s+

Comment: or place one of them inside the ( )?

Comment: Note that if the regex captures \n with . or if there are multiple instances on one line, this should be non-greedy: (\d*) (\(.*?\))? Z

Comment: Thank you for the `?:` non-captured group suggestion, that's so easy.

Answer (score 23):

This ought to work:

```
^\d+\s?(\([^\)]+\)\s?)?Z$
```

Haven't tested it though, but let me give you the breakdown, so if there are any bugs left they should be pretty straightforward to find:

First the beginning:

```
^ = beginning of string
\d+ = one or more decimal characters
\s? = one optional whitespace
```

Then this part:

```
(\([^\)]+\)\s?)?
```

Is actually:

```
(.............)?
```

Which makes the following contents optional, only if it exists fully

```
\([^\)]+\)\s?

\( = an opening bracket
[^\)]+ = a series of at least one character that is not a closing bracket
\) = followed by a closing bracket
\s? = followed by one optional whitespace
```

And the end is made up of

```
Z$
```

Where

```
Z = your constant string
$ = the end of the string
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```
([0-9]+) (\([^)]+\))? Z
```

This will not work with nested parens for Y, however. Nesting requires recursion which isn't strictly regular any more (but context-free). Modern regexp engines can still handle it, albeit with some difficulties (back-references).

Comment: Fortunately I don't think I need to handle nested parens.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
X (\(Y\))? Z
```